# On ATM using java, what is the OS?

Tags: java

I ve recently installed Java and saw the add on the windows installer:

"3 Billions devices uses Java"

And I m wondering, Java does have a virtual machine which allow to run on any platforms, yeah, but it can t boot the device.

I know Android run Java, but it is on a Linux base.

So my question is, what does thoses device, (let s say ATM if the question is too broad) use as OS?

Comment: ATMs use special patched versions on Windows XP

Comment: Most ATMs on my experience work on Windows NT/WindowsXP OS-es.

Comment: Java ME edition is/was bundled on a lot of feature phones, which I suspect is a great part of that number.

Comment: I've seen WinXPs on Wincor Nixdorf ATMs. I've also seen others with Blue Screens of Death.. so definitely some version of Windows...

Comment: [Java Card](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/Java-Card)s exist which have an on-chip JVM. They may well contribute significantly to the "3 billion" quoted.

Comment: theres also lots of older mobile phones which used java for applications. it was state of the art around 7 years ago. my samsung outdoor mobile phone still has java on it. thats a lot of devices in the world

Comment: Some ARM CPUs have an extension named [Jazelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Jazelle) to directly run Java bytecode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, each device would have an os  or we can say system software which loads jvm .all java applications run in jvm environment. but i wanted to mentioned that most of atm machined using windows os with .net applications.

Answer (score 1):

Watch [this video](http://vimeo.com/18582091), and you will see how an ATM was hacked.

It shows the ATM running some kind of windows os